# backbone.js change model sub attribute not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

my model is defined like this:

```
model{
name;
number;
subLines[ ]; ->array object:subtitle,status
}
```

I used this way to change the sublines attribute

```
this.model.get("subLines").foreach(function(line){
line.status = "submited"
});

console.log(this.model);---> yes,the subLines status was changed
this.model.save();
```

But the change was not saved.
why? is there other way to change model sub attributes?

Comment: `But the change was not saved.` where? do you mean by server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making changes to attribute which is an array, there is no way backbone can figure it out. better way of doing this is

```
var subLines = this.model.get('subLines');
_.each(subLines,function(item){
    item.status = 'submitted';
})
this.model.set('subLines');
```

this shall trigger change:subLines event on the model.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the model's status attribute directly, you'll be missing out on all the functionality made available by the model's set method, which include firing a "change" event. It's hard to be certain from the details you've given, but simply changing:

```
line.status = "submitted"
```

to:

```
line.set({ status: "submitted" })
```

might just fix your problem.

Comment: More accurately, `model.attribute` and `model.get('attribute')` are entirely different things. `line.status = 'x'` doesn't do the same thing as `line.set('status', 'x')` and `line.save()` only knows about the `line.set('status', 'x')` version.